# Is it possible to replace empty string with custom text in PHP?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm using str_replace() PHP function which doesn't replace empty string.

Is it possible to replace it using some other PHP functions?

Here is my code:

```
  $var = "text1|text2";
  $expn = explode("|", $var);

  $new = "new text";

  str_replace($expn[1], $new,  $var);
```

This code really works, but if the second value is empty it doesn't:

```
  $var = "text1|";

  $expn = explode("|", $var);

  $new = "new text";

  str_replace($expn[1], $new,  $var);
```

I want this to echo text1|new text but it doesnt. In the first case it does without a problem. I want this to be changed anyway, it doesn't depend if it's empty or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are exploding `text1|` at the |, theres nothing after the |.. so theres nothing in `$expn[1]` either you are asking a question i dont understand or you should be using `$expn[0]`

Comment: @robz228 of course there is: `var_dump( explode("|", "something|") );` It's an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this after your `explode()`:

```
if ($expn[1] == '') {
  $var .= 'new text';
} else {
  str_replace($expn[1], $new,  $var);
}
```

Comment: Of course!!! Never thought of that. Thank you very much. I'll accept answer in minutes.

Comment: I've actually edited the code to be more correct after reading your question again, but you're welcome!